# timeStamp of form submit

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to check the timestamp of the form submission. I'm trying to get the `timeStamp` of the event but that returns the 1/1/1970 date always. How to do that correctly?

```js
$('#form').on('submit', (event) => {
  console.log(new Date(event.timeStamp).toLocaleDateString("en-UK"))
})
```

```css
body {
  background: white; /* try type yellow */
  color: #323232;

  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  font-family: Helvetica neue, roboto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: The `timeStamp` property gives you the time in milliseconds between when the page was loaded to when the event was fired. You'd be better off with just `new Date()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-UK"), and forget the timestamp from the event. It will give you the result you're looking for.